# Add price of duplicate object to first unique object in array using JavaScript only

Tags: javascript, arrays

Input array

```
[{ id: 1, title: 'shirt', price: 2000 }, 
{ id: 2, title: 'shirt', price: 4000}, 
{ id: 3,  title: 'tshirt', price: 10000}]
```

Expected output

```
[{ id: 1, title: 'shirt', price: 6000 },          // 2000 + 4000
{ id: 3,  title: 'tshirt', price: 10000}]
```

Have tried multiple ways to achieve but couldn't get a solution.

I'm able to get unique objects but need the addition of price as well

```
let result = products.filter((product, index, self) =>
  index === self.findIndex((t) => (t.title === product.title))
)
console.log(result);
```

Comment: what about `id`? should it take the first one?

Comment: @NinaScholz yeah duplicate price should add to the first matched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take an object as hash bale for same title and get the values from the object.

```js
const
    data = [{ id: 1, title: 'shirt', price: 2000 }, { id: 2, title: 'shirt', price: 4000}, { id: 3,  title: 'tshirt', price: 10000}],
    result = Object.values(data.reduce((r, o) => {
        if (r[o.title]) r[o.title].price += o.price;
        else r[o.title] = { ...o };
        return r;
    }, {}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks, Really it solved my problem.